# Anyway to pass a mat icon to the mat-tab-nav-bar?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is what I am going for:

[image: What I'm going for]

Associated code:

```
<mat-tab-group color="warn" [selectedIndex]="0" (selectedTabChange)="routerControl($event)">
            <mat-tab label="About"></mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Projects"></mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="News & Press"></mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Contact Us"></mat-tab>
            <mat-tab> 
                <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
                </ng-template>

            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
```

This is where I'm currently at: 
[image: Current iteration]

Associated Code:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
        <a mat-tab-link
                *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
                [routerLink]="link.path"
                routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
                [active]="rla.isActive">
            {{link.label}}
        </a>
    </nav>
```

Typescript Code:

```
this.navLinks = [{
                      path: '',
                      label: 'About'
                    },
                    {
                      path: 'projects',
                      label: 'Projects'
                    },
                    {
                      path: 'news',
                      label: 'News'
                    },
                    {
                      path: 'contact',
                      label: 'Contact Us'
                    },
                    {
                      path: 'search',
                      label: ''
                    }
                    ]
```

***Question:***

How do I get the search mat-icon in the mat-tab-link version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple add the icon if it exists:

```js
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
        <a mat-tab-link
                *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
                [routerLink]="link.path"
                routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
                [active]="rla.isActive">
            {{link.label}}
            <mat-icon *ngIf="link.icon">{{link.icon}}</mat-icon>
        </a>
    </nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your NavLink interface add an optional field as matIcon

```
export interface NavLink {
    label?: string // Also you can make label optional as it won't appear with icon
    matIcon?: string;
}

<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link
            *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
            [routerLink]="link.path"
            routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
            [active]="rla.isActive">
        {{link.label}} <mat-icon *ngIf="link.matIcon">{{link.matIcon}}</mat-icon>
    </a>
</nav>
```

Provide Slackbitz if this doesn't help.